# How do model deeply nested relationships in AWS Amplify/AppSync

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to model a deeply nested relationship and am getting a strange data structure in response when querying for the outcome. Here is my `schemal.graphql` file:

```js
type Page @model {
  id: ID!
  settings: String
  active_menu: ID
}

type MenuItemOption @model @key(name: "byMenuItem", fields: ["menuitemID"]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  price: Int
  menuitemID: ID!
}

type MenuItem @model @key(name: "byMenuSection", fields: ["menusectionID"]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  menusectionID: ID!
  description: String
  price: Int
  options: [MenuItemOption] @connection(keyName: "byMenuItem", fields: ["id"])
}

type MenuSection @model @key(name: "byMenu", fields: ["menuID"]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  menuID: ID!
  items: [MenuItem] @connection(keyName: "byMenuSection", fields: ["id"])
}

type Menu @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  sections: [MenuSection] @connection(keyName: "byMenu", fields: ["id"])
}
```

The data structure returned by creating a Menu + Section appears as follows (in a truncated form):

```json
[
  {
    "id": "5edf6975-f63e-4dcd-95e1-25ff197080d8",
    "title": "New Menu",
    "sections": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "511e9629-efed-4cd0-b146-d348b99bf30f",
          "title": "New Section",
          "menuID": "5edf6975-f63e-4dcd-95e1-25ff197080d8",
          "items": { "items": [], "nextToken": null, "startedAt": null },
          "_version": 1,
          "_deleted": null,
        }
      ],
      "nextToken": null,
      "startedAt": null
    },
    "_version": 1,
    "_deleted": null,
  },
  {
    "id": "2a6df8e1-7def-42b0-be78-70ed5685ac8b",
    "title": "Another menu",
    "sections": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "99c75a0a-2e76-425a-9788-77b8ddf4f991",
          "title": "Another section title",
          "menuID": "2a6df8e1-7def-42b0-be78-70ed5685ac8b",
          "items": { "items": [], "nextToken": null, "startedAt": null },
          "_version": 1,
          "_deleted": null,
        }
      ],
      "nextToken": null,
      "startedAt": null
    },
    "_version": 1,
  }
]
```

There appears to be an extra `items` property under `sections` that contains the details of a `Section`. What I would like instead is for there to be a direct nested data structure representing the model without the intermediary properties. Example:

```json
{
menus: {
    title: 'a menu title',
    sections: [
      {
        title: 'a section title'
        items: [{ title: 'an item title' }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I either model the schema such that the intermediary `items` property is not present or query for the correct structure? I am new to GraphQL. Thanks in advance.